# How to post value using CURL php function?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have created a wordpress plugin,i want to send status while activating that plugin using curl. 
here is my code to send status

```
  function send_Status($data){    
    $handle = curl_init("http://www.example.com/testpage.php");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $rtnval=curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
    return $rtnval;
  }
```

$data is an array with status,But i am getting null array in http://www.example.com/testpage.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    "name" => "alex",
    "pass" => "test123"
);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```